# c++ compilation error with listing_6_6.cpp from book C++ Concurrency In Action

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to compile the example listing_6.6.cpp from the book "C++ Concurrency In Action" of Anthony Williams, but it's not compiling and I don't understand why.

I'm new to multithreading, but I've checked the code and googled for an answer, but I still don't understand why it doesn't compile.

The problem is in this method:

```
std::unique_ptr<node> pop_head()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> head_lock(head_mutex);
    if (head.get() == get_tail())
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    std::unique_ptr<node> const old_head = std::move(head);
    head = std::move(old_head->next);
    return old_head;   // <-- here is the problem
}
```

the error message is: attempting to reference a deleted function

The full error message is (I'm using VS 2013):

```
threadsafe_queue.h(34): error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<threadsafe_queue<Message>::node,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
```

and the full code is:

```
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>

template<typename T>
class threadsafe_queue
{
private:
   struct node
   {
      std::shared_ptr<T> data;
      std::unique_ptr<node> next;
   };

   std::mutex head_mutex;
   std::unique_ptr<node> head;
   std::mutex tail_mutex;
   node* tail;

   node* get_tail()
   {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> tail_lock(tail_mutex);
      return tail;
   }

   std::unique_ptr<node> pop_head()
   {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> head_lock(head_mutex);
      if (head.get() == get_tail())
      {
         return nullptr;
      }
      std::unique_ptr<node> const old_head = std::move(head);
      head = std::move(old_head->next);
      return old_head;
   }


public:
   threadsafe_queue() :
      head(new node), tail(head.get())
   {}

   threadsafe_queue(const threadsafe_queue& other) = delete;
   threadsafe_queue& operator=(const threadsafe_queue& other) = delete;

   std::shared_ptr<T> try_pop()
   {
      std::unique_ptr<node> old_head = pop_head();
      return old_head ? old_head->data : std::shared_ptr<T>();
   }

   void push(T new_value)
   {
      std::shared_ptr<T> new_data(
         std::make_shared<T>(std::move(new_value)));
      std::unique_ptr<node> p(new node);
      node* const new_tail = p.get();
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> tail_lock(tail_mutex);
      tail->data = new_data;
      tail->next = std::move(p);
      tail = new_tail;
   }
};
```

Thansk!

Comment: In `push`, `new_data` is copied into `tail->data` when it could more efficiently be moved: `tail->data = std::move(new_data);`.

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR:** You can't move from a `const` object, even when returning.

The constructor selected to initialize the return value of `pop_head` from a `const unique_ptr` is the deleted copy constructor, so the compiler is correct to reject this program as ill-formed. If you look at Listing 6.6 in the book itself (page 161-162) you'll notice that the offending `const` is not present.